# Getting [BOT NAME] not responding

Tags: google-hangouts

I created hangouts chat bot using google cloud function. Function executes fine from google cloud console. But when I add bot in hangouts chat and send message, I repeatedly get message bot not responding. If I return simple request message back in response, it works. But as soon as I add any dynamic code, it stops working. I am using nodejs 8 runtime in google cloud functions.

**Update: Added code of cloud function.**

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.getProjects = (req, res) => {
  const https = require("http");

const options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": "api2.quickscrum.com",
    "port": 80,
    "path": "/api/getSingleProjectDetails?projectId=0000&Company_id=00000",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "123/dassdd==",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
}

const qs_req = https.request(options, function(qs_res) {

    var chunks = [];

    qs_res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    qs_res.on("end", function() {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(JSON.parse(body.toString()));
        res.status(200).send(JSON.parse(body.toString()));
    });

});

qs_req.end()

};
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you shared the code for your bot.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same issue.
I see the "bot not responding" error if I send a json response to the event.
When I return a blank response to google chat event I do not see the error.
I am using the rest api but this should give you a clue.